# Transparency on OBJ after export - Why and how to stop it

Tags: transparency

I have a OBJ Rose which when popped into blender looks great. I'm trying to export each individual petal as its own OBJ to manipulate separately elsewhere.

Every time I export each or even the whole thing as an OBJ the front facing petal is see through. See image:

[image]
[image]
[image]

As you can see in the last image, if I look at the petal from the other side (Bottom of image) it looks okay, but when viewed from the front its transparent, but in blender looks okay.

Any help would be most appreciated!

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: It depends on the shading of the program not on the model or the format. Most of the game engines renders the front face only. If you turn on backface culling in Blender you will see the same there too. You can solve this by adding a little thickness to the mesh with the solidify modifier. If the front face and back face overlaps each other it doesn't count because backfaces are invisible.

Comment: You are a gent! Backface and adding very very little to the petals worked a treat!